# What punctuation should I use?

Tags: punctuation

"...on the last - 3rd day of the 3-day trip."

Is this part of the sentence correct? What punctuation should I use?

Comment: "on the last day of the three-day trip". We commonly use words for small numbers (e.g. smaller than 11). No need to tell the reader twice that the day is the third (of three).

Comment: but is it grammatically correct? Is my punctuation correct?

Comment: You can enclose '3rd' in brackets, commas, or dashes.

Comment: "...on the last ,3rd, day of the 3-day trip", or "...on the last, - 3rd, day of the 3-day trip", which one is correct? Sorry english is not my native language but I need to check exactly this sentence and use a correct punctuation :)

Comment: on the last - third - day of the three-day trip, on the last (third) day of the three-day trip, on the last, third, day of the three-day trip. I repeat - your use of figures for '3rd' and '3-day' is clumsy and inelegant, and why are you telling the reader twice in one sentence that the third day is the last day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A remark inserted as extra information, like '3rd' in your example is called a parenthetical remark or insertion, and can be marked in a number of ways:

> Em dashes: I enjoyed the last — third — day of my trip. Putting spaces before and after an em dash is a matter of preference; just be consistent.
>
> Parentheses: I enjoyed the last (third) day of my trip.
>
> Parenthetical commas: I enjoyed the last, third, day of my trip.

[Em dash](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/why-you-should-love-the-em-dash/#:%7E:text=Use%20Em%20Dashes%20to%20Set%20Off%20Parenthetical%20Information&text=Using%20em%20dashes%20instead%20of,information%20and%20one%20after%20it.)

[Dashes](http://academics.smcvt.edu/writingctr/Dashes.htm)

[Comma usage](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/commas.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You really do not need to write the word *third* or *3rd* as the sentence is self explanatory without it. Last of a three-day trip would certainly mean **the third day** of the trip.

However, if you still want to write it for leaving no place for ambiguity, I would say, place them in ***round brackets ()*** (also called as parentheses). Readers would know that it is an extra bit of information that they could either skip entirely or read for their own satisfaction.

> [...] on the last (third) day of the three-day trip [...]
>
> [...] on the last (3rd) day of the 3-day trip [...]

[Brief information about bracket usages in English](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823034002/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/parentheses-and-brackets)

Other alternatives:

- Place them in ***Em dashes*** (long dashes **(—)**).

> [...] on the last—third—day of the three-day trip [...]
>
> [...] on the last—3rd—day of the 3-day trip [...]

***NOTE:*** *There is no space added on either sides of an em dash.*

[Brief information on the usage of Em dash](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/em-dash/)

- Place them in **between a pair of commas** (.., [ ], ..).

> [...] on the last, third, day of the three-day trip [...]
>
> [...] on the last, 3rd, day of the 3-day trip [...]

[Brief information on using commas to mark off parts of a sentence](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823033938/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/comma#grammar/comma#commas_to_mark_off_parts_of_a_sentence)

Comment: You're supposed to do the research _before_ you post an answer.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I was certain about the usage of round brackets and hence I had posted it. I can delete my answer if you want (I know it shows that I blindly copied your comment, but it is not the case).

Comment: "MichaelHarvey, for writing your name incorrectly" -- I did not see that! Spaces before and after em dashes are a matter of preference.

Comment: I had written Micheal instead of Michael, silly me!! Thank God, @rjpond pointed it out. And I did not that fact regarding spaces. I personally always use brackets, sometimes commas and never really used em dashes ever in my life. Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: "I had written Micheal" - my own daughter does that.